# Paint when mouse is over an image

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I'm working on Window application based on .Net 2.0.

I have used picture box to show an image. Use have ability of drawing lines on that image. Picturebox sizemode is set to zoom. Now the image opened in picture box is showing in center of picturebox with spaces around image.

The code I'm having is able to paint on picturebox. But I want to restrict painting on picturebox. User should be able to paint only on image of picturebox.

Can you guide me in that context?

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code only writes into the image somewhere in the picturebox. Hope this is what you have in mind.

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var p = new Pen(Color.Red, 5f);
    var pbox = sender as PictureBox;
    var area = (Bitmap)pbox.Image;
    var g = Graphics.FromImage(area);

    g.DrawEllipse(p, e.X, e.Y, 5, 5);
    pbox.Image = area;

    p.Dispose();
    g.Dispose();
}
```